# Flutter intercept Image.network network call

Tags: flutter, image, http

I am using `Image.network` to load network image. But we also keep SQLite DB containing local path of image captured by user.
i want to intercept the `Image.network` call and check if the image exists in internal storage if not then only make network call.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score -1):

With my current knowledge, either you can keep track of your current locally stored image path and check if it exists or not. and then put them in a try and catch block to load locally and if that end up in an error, load network image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).